# Repair Visual Studio after a clean Windows installation

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

My Windows installation got corrupt and I had to reinstall it, which wiped my whole Windows(C:) drive. I installed Visual Studio on D: drive which remained intact. Now, when I start it, it tells me to reinstall it. There is no 'Visual Studio 2015' in **Add or Remove Programs** (as it is not in the new registry). Is there anyway I can repair it **WITHOUT** having to reinstall the WHOLE Visual Studio package again?

Comment: You also lost the registry, VS uses a *lot* of registry keys.  Reinstalling it is required.  Just like the message says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete Visual Studio on D:, then install it again from the original installer.

Comment: Please see the updated question. I want to repair it instead of reinstalling it as installing Visual Studio was the hardest thing I ever did on a PC.

Comment: Repair means uninstall+reinstall. What is hard about it?

Comment: Ok, I will reinstall, it although the last time I tried to install it, it wasted ~15 GBs of internet and took me 2 weeks to figure out the problems and install it...